# Dereferenced list iterator segfault

Tags: c++, list, iterator, segmentation-fault, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm putting together a parser for a language in bison/flex and have been implementing the abstract syntax tree. As soon as I implemented some very primitive static type checking though, I've started to get segmentation faults on my list iterator, that is iterating through my statements list.

The root program node that holds the list iterator:

```
program::program(list<statement *> *stmtList) : stmts(stmtList) {}

void program::evaluate() {
   list<statement *>::iterator stmtIter;
   for (stmtIter = stmts->begin(); stmtIter != stmts->end();
      stmtIter++) {
     (*stmtIter)->evaluate();
  }
}
```

stmtList is a pointer to a list of pointers to statements. it has to be a pointer to a list because bison to accomodate bison not accepting types requiring constructors in `%union`

an example of a statement node that it is failing upon is

```
void declare_assign_stmt::evaluate() 
{
    reference * ref;
    ref->type = type;

    if(ref->type != exp->type)
    {
        cerr << "Incompatible types!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        ref->location = exp->evaluate();;
        idTable[id] = ref;
    };
```

}

`reference` is a struct with two fields, `type` and `location`, a string and int respectively. idTable is a map of id's to reference pointers. `exp` is a pointer to my expression node, and it evaluates correctly and returns an int. i've stepped through this function and everything behaves as expected, but upon completing `evaluate()`, it will return to the iteration loop, and even if the list contained no more elements, the loop will continue and `(*stmtIter)` will next point to a location where no statement exists, thus giving the segmentation fault. nothing within a statements evaluation manipulates the list.

some insight would be great. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reference * ref;
ref->type = type;
```

You did not initialize that pointer. The compiler should really warn you about that. Did you enable all available compiler warnings?

Comment: i edited to clarify reference is a struct. i'm not sure of what sort of initialization is required, but stepping through it in gdb, the structure is created and the values are set appropriately.

Comment: `ref` is only a pointer to `struct reference`. Initially it points anywhere, probably at some location near the current stack pointer.

Comment: that did indeed fix it! thank you. i do wonder however why the segmentation fault would occur on the iterator, and why it would behave the way i observed under such circumstances.

Comment: My guess is that the initial value of `ref` is a pointer somewhere near the stack pointer, as I already said. When you then assign some value to `ref->type`, some value of the stack gets overwritten. Maybe it’s a return address, maybe it’s the iterator (the local variable from the calling function).